# Generating automated bullets and numbered lists with markdown

Tags: filetype-markdown, plugin-vim-pandoc

I'm looking for a good way to generate lists that are automatically bulleted. I tried the markdown plugin. It generates bullets automatically but not numbered lists. I also tried the vim-pandoc plugin which handles markdown but it doesn't do automated bullets or numbers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an inbuilt feature in vim, write this

```
1)
```

use `yy5p` to paste 5 (or use any number) lines of number 1)

```
1)
1)
1)
1)
1)
1)
```

Now select from the second to the last line and press `g` then `Ctrl+A`. It will populate numbered lists automatically as

```
1)
2)
3)
4)
5)
6)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just discovered the "bullets" plugin. Seems to do the job perfectly: https://github.com/dkarter/bullets.vim